# Using jQuery with WebDriver (JAVA)

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, webdriver

**Hi all!**

I use WebDriver to automate the test packets. Please help to solve one problem: does not work use the jQuery .. always get the error

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: TypeError: $(...) is null

**Testing code:**

```
@Test
public void stage003() throws Exception {
    Reporter.log("<p class=\"stageDescr\">Check for uniqueness of identifiers</p>");
    JQSS("" +
        "var D_id=\"\";" +
        "$('[id]').each(function(){" +
            "var ids = $('[id=\"'+this.id+'\"]');" +
            "if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this) {" +
                "D_id = D_id + \" \" + this.id;" +
            "}" +
        "});" +
        "if (D_id==\"\") {" +
            "return D_id = \"All ID's is unique\";" +
        "} else {" +
            "return D_id;" +
        "}" +               
    "");
    Reporter.log("<p class=\"stageOutline\">                                   </p>");
}
```

**And**

```
public void JQSS(String SC) {
    String test = (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
        SC
    );
    Reporter.log("<p>Testing report... "+test+ "</p>");
}
```

PS: jquery on the page is already connected

Comment: In what browser is this? Have you run your script against the page manually? (Using something like Firebug)

Comment: FF 21
This test script I used on the test page. Firebug does not show any errors. Everything works perfectly and correctly.
The test for JS and jQuery checks for duplicates page by ID's

Comment: I've used JQuery successfully on a page using JavascriptExecutor, nothing special required.  I'm guessing that this is a waiting-for-the -page-to-load problem, which I have run into quite a few times.  You can either wait for JQuery using Javascript, or you can try-catch the exception in a loop until JQuery is loaded.

Comment: Hmmm... You can please an example? I tried to put a delay ... did not help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - on the test page was also MooTols. I changed the $ sign on "jQuery" and it worked